# Multilingual Content Websites ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Resource Files are mostly used to enable multilingual websites. What about data stored in the database? What if some "reference data" like Drop Downs in a website need to be multilingual.

Is it enough storing an additional column for each data record specifying the language a record belongs to?

Answer (score 1):

[Extending the ASP.NET 2.0 Resource-Provider Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905797.aspx) has a sample implementation of a database resource provider. This, of course, if you want to stick with the .NET native resource manager model, something I would avoid as I'm not sure if it's flexible enough.